# React router not changing paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import * as React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link,useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./login/index";
import MainFrame from "./main-frame/index";

const MainWrapper = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>      
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/main-frame">
          <MainFrame  /> 
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/">
          <Login />
          </Route> 
          <Route exact path="/i">
          <p>sdf</p>
          </Route>       
        </Switch>
      </Router> 
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainWrapper;
```

This is my simple code. When I go to brower and enter manually **http://localhost:8080/i**, Path is not changing. Only  **http://localhost:8080/** works. Neither  **http://localhost:8080/main-frame** works.
Both of the above gives error:

```
Cannot GET /i
```

```
Cannot GET /main-frame
```

Comment: try to put <Route exact path="/"> first.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must fix it

```js
<Router>      
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/main-frame" component={MainFrame} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
    {/* <Route exact path="/i"> */}
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

reference this https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91